# Why does backtrader not display time when backtesting?

Tags: python, datetime, time, back-testing

I am trying to backtest a strategy with Backtrader and have a problem while printing date & time for each iteration (time stay on 23:59:59).

Here are the first lines of my dataset:

[image: Lines of dataset]

What is printed on the console :

[image: Console log]

And finally how I load my data :

```
data = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData(dataname="BTCUSD_15MIN.csv",
                               datetime=0,
                               fromdate=datetime.datetime(2015,1,13),
                               todate=datetime.datetime(2015,1,15),
                               open=1,
                               high=2,
                               low=3,
                               close=4,
                               openinterest=-1,
                               time=-1,
                               volume=-1,
                               dtformat="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Has someone already got this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That for sure only solved your problem by chance (because what you chose is smaller than the actual reality)

Your data is obviously `15-minutes` based. But without specification, you let the default values in place: `bt.TimeFrame.Daily`, which gives you the **end of the day** for each bar. No surprises there.

The right choice would therefore be:

```
timeframe=bt.TimeFrame.Minutes,
compression=15,
```

This is explained in the *backtrader* community in several posts and in the FAQ.

- FAQ: https://community.backtrader.com/topic/381/faq
- One post with the same content: https://community.backtrader.com/topic/244/backtesting-1-minute-data/

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line to the data feed sorted out my problem:

```
timeframe=bt.TimeFrame.Ticks
```

If interested in the strategy result, it's [here](https://myfinancialmarkets.club/2017/11/23/backtest-a-trading-strategy-in-python/).